# ModuleNotFoundError while importing from alias

Tags: python, import, alias

e.g.

```
import os as my_os
import my_os.path
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_os'

but the following script is ok

```
import os
import os.path
```

Comment: You already imported `my_os`, just use it: `my_os.path`

Comment: `import os.path as osp` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in Python.

1. `import` statements are importing from Python file names.
2. You aren't renaming the file of `os` to `my_os`, therefore this wouldn't work.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system):

> The `import` statement combines two operations; it searches for the named module, then it binds the results of that search to a name in the local scope.

Comment: But `os.path` is actually an alias to posixpath or ntpath (see /usr/lib/python3.6/os.py). Not sure why `import os.path` is ok.

Comment: @kkaaii Is because the module name is `os`, which is what you import.

Comment: @kkaaii The rapped up module is named `os`, which maybe imports `posixpath` and `ntpath`, but it is rapped up as `os`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the similar way as os.py did:

```
import json as my_json
from my_json.decoder import *   # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_json'

import sys
import json.decoder as my_decoder
sys.modules['my_json.decoder'] = my_decoder
from my_json.decoder import *   # it's ok now
```

Comment: Now it works is because `import` imports from `sys.modules`, where now you renamed it on this instance, so therefore it works...

Comment: I removed the first 2 lines and the script still works. Seems my_json is no longer an alias. You're correct, it does import form sys.modules. @U12-Forward